# Can we say without aliasing, pointer and reference are of the exactly the same thing

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Both performance-wise and functionality-wise?

Which means, if you want to modifiy the contents of some data pointed by some pointer during a function call, passing pointer arguments works exactly the same as passing reference arguments?

Comment: As soon as you mention references, you can't possibly tag this with C.

Answer (score 2):

Performance-wise, references perform slightly better than pointers. That has to do with pointer adjustment needed in certain cases, for instance when *multiple inheritance* is in place. When the converted pointer is *null*, the adjustment has to be reversed (or not done at all) so that the pointer remains *null*. The fact that references cannot be *null* mean that an extra check is not needed.

Functionality-wise, pointers can be *null* while references can´t, and pointers can be reassigned while references can´t. Other than the basic different syntax to access them.

So basically no, they are not exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Good point, more scenarios where references are slightly better performance-wise then...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Would you mind editing the answer yourself? I need to do some more research in light of the point you just raised until I fully understand it.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf: I see what you mean, not even a `static_cast` is needed.